# Django Postgresql Error in Production (quiz.models.Question.DoesNotExist:)

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am creating a quiz application using a guide. My application works perfectly fine in development with both sqlite3 and postgresql databases. But when pushed to production, I am faced with errors using a postgresql database. So I tried using my development sqlite3 database in production to test things out. My sqlite3 database works fine in production, but postgresql does not work in production. Initially, I thought the error is on the views level, but now I am seeing the error coming from the postgresql. Could be errors in my views or models schema. I really can't tell. The corresponding error I get when using a postgresql database in production using a linux server with gunicorn and nginx is here below, and the whole models design and views are here below too. Thanks, I appreciate your time in giving me a suitable answer to my question.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
import random
from account.models import Profile
from django.urls import reverse
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone
from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField


class PublishedBookManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(PublishedBookManager, self).get_queryset().filter(publish_book=True)

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField()
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(Profile, default=1, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    number_of_questions = models.IntegerField()
    number_of_sections = models.IntegerField()
    time = models.IntegerField(help_text="duration of the quiz in minutes")
    required_score_to_pass = models.IntegerField(help_text="required score in %")
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    publish_book = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    objects = models.Manager() 
    published = PublishedBookManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('quiz:book-detail-view', args=[self.pk])


class PublishedQuizManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(PublishedQuizManager, self).get_queryset().filter(publish_quiz=True)


class Quiz(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField()
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(Profile, default=1, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    number_of_questions = models.IntegerField()
    time = models.IntegerField(help_text="duration of the quiz in minutes")
    required_score_to_pass = models.IntegerField(help_text="required score in %")
    completed_users = models.ManyToManyField(Profile, blank=True, related_name='completed_users_quiz')
    publish_quiz = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    deadline_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    objects = models.Manager() 
    published = PublishedQuizManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.book.name} = {self.name}"

    def get_questions(self):
        questions = list(self.question_set.all())
        random.shuffle(questions)
        return questions[:self.number_of_questions]


    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Quizes'


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('quiz:quiz-view',  kwargs={'book_pk': self.book.pk, "pk": self.pk})

class Question(models.Model):
    # text = models.TextField()
    text = RichTextUploadingField(unique=True)
    second_text = models.TextField()
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.text)

    def get_answers(self):
        return self.answer_set.all()

    # def get_absolute_url(self):
    #     return reverse('quiz:quiz-view', kwargs={'question_pk': self.pk,})

class Answer(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    correct = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"question: {self.question.text}, answer: {self.text}, correct: {self.correct}"

class Result(models.Model):
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    score = models.FloatField()
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pk)
```

**views.py**

```
def save_quiz_view(request, pk, book_pk):
    # if request.user in 
    quiz = Quiz.objects.get(pk=pk)
    # Submition of result only occurs if a user is not in the completed users field. If they are already
    #  in the completed users ManyToMany field, then it won't save. But if not, it will save.
    if request.is_ajax() and not request.user.profile in quiz.completed_users.all():
        questions = []
        data = request.POST
        data_ = dict(data.lists())

        data_.pop('csrfmiddlewaretoken')

        for _k in data_.keys():
            if Question.objects.all():
                # print('key: ', k)
                k = _k
                question = Question.objects.get(text=k)
                questions.append(question)

        user = request.user.profile
        quiz = Quiz.objects.get(pk=pk)

        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            if not user in quiz.completed_users.all():
                quiz.completed_users.add(user)

        score = 0
        multiplier = 100 / quiz.number_of_questions
        results = []
        correct_answer = None

        for q in questions:
            a_selected = request.POST.get(q.text)

            if a_selected != "":
                question_answers = Answer.objects.filter(question=q)
                for a in question_answers:
                    if a_selected == a.text:
                        if a.correct:
                            score += 1
                            correct_answer = a.text
                    else:
                        if a.correct:
                            correct_answer = a.text

                results.append({str(q): {'correct_answer': correct_answer, 'answered': a_selected}})
            else:
                results.append({str(q): 'not answered'})
            
        score_ = score #* multiplier
        Result.objects.create(quiz=quiz, user=user, score=score_)

        if score_:#>= quiz.required_score_to_pass:
            return JsonResponse({'passed': True, 'score': score_, 'results': results})
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'passed': False, 'score': score_, 'results': results})
```

**Error**

```
django@UniqueAsf2:~/src$ python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
October 26, 2021 - 03:57:12
Django version 3.2.8, using settings 'asf.settings'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[26/Oct/2021 03:57:18] "GET /quiz/1/1/ HTTP/1.1" 200 8065
Not Found: /quiz/1/1/assets/vendors/boxicons/css/boxicons.min.css
[26/Oct/2021 03:57:18] "GET /quiz/1/1/assets/vendors/boxicons/css/boxicons.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 5612
[26/Oct/2021 03:57:18] "GET /quiz/1/1/data/ HTTP/1.1" 200 101
Internal Server Error: /quiz/1/1/save/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/django/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/django/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/django/src/quiz/views.py", line 108, in save_quiz_view
    question = Question.objects.get(text=_k)
  File "/home/django/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/django/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 435, in get
    raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
quiz.models.Question.DoesNotExist: Question matching query does not exist.
```

Comment: The record does not exist. Not really something broken with your db. Why not manually create the record via admin and reload the webpage (will give you confirmation this is the issue).

Comment: I manually created the records using the admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

Your data in `Question` is not stored in simple text because you are using `RichTextUploadingField` which converts text into HTML format for handling text fomatting. Because of this you can't directly compare two strings or run search over it.

Try using [icontains](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#icontains) for checking string in your field. This might not work in all cases so you'll have to handle that accordingly.

```
questions = Question.objects.filter(text__icontains=k)
for question in questions:
    # Handle questions here
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll try this immediately and give a feedback on my result. Although, initially I used the "text" filed with just Django TextField it still returned the error in production before the changes with RichTextEditor.

Comment: Comparing two strings directly is always risky as little difference can fail your query. Try implementing some sort of search for this. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/search/